# Why does RSquared increase with # of folds in k-fold cross validation?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, r-caret

I'm tuning a model using k-fold cross-validation and noticed that the RSquared accuracy appears to improve with the number of folds -- e.g. you get a higher RSquared value when using 30 folds compared to using 10 folds.

Two questions I was hoping for some insight on:

1. Why does this occur?
2. Is there any reason to believe that the RSquared for k=10 is a better estimate of model accuracy than using k=30? Or are they both unrelated to the future error rate I can expect on an unseen test set?

Here's a simple example of the effect I'm referring to:

```
############### k = 10 #####################
> data(iris)
> train_control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=3)
> train(Sepal.Length~.,data=iris,trControl=train_control,method="rf",metric="Rsquared")

Random Forest 

150 samples
4 predictor

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 3 times) 
Summary of sample sizes: 137, 135, 134, 134, 135, 136, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

mtry  RMSE       Rsquared   RMSE SD     Rsquared SD
2     0.3381065  0.8404534  0.07692415  0.07583768 
3     0.3247406  0.8502577  0.07311807  0.07326181 
5     0.3228651  0.8517740  0.07213958  0.07315720 

############### k = 30 #####################
> data(iris)
> train_control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=30, repeats=3)
> train(Sepal.Length~.,data=iris,trControl=train_control,method="rf",metric="Rsquared")

Random Forest 

150 samples
4 predictor

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (30 fold, repeated 3 times) 
Summary of sample sizes: 143, 145, 146, 144, 145, 144, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

mtry  RMSE       Rsquared   RMSE SD     Rsquared SD
2     0.3238545  0.8580474  0.10327919  0.1352787  
3     0.3119541  0.8679321  0.09734168  0.1236307  
5     0.3109572  0.8717550  0.09727307  0.1123173
```

Answer (score 0):

Bigger number of folds - bigger the training set and smaller the testing one. You will nearly always observe the best result fo LOO (N-fold with N training samples) and the worst with k=2. There is no one answer for a generic question how many folds to use, it solely depends on your dataset. Furthermore if there is any underlying relation between your datapoints (for example they come from the time series) then it is important how the set is divided.